# Corda - why is deployNodes outputting a useless JAR?

Tags: corda

*I'm performing this on Windows, so some of these operations might be different for Linux/Mac users.*

### Steps To Reproduce

**Step 1:** Clone the [Corda V3 Kotlin template](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin.git) into a new folder

`git clone https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin.git MyFirstCorDapp`

**Step 2:** clean and deploy nodes with gradle

`./gradlew clean dN`

### Output

This image illustrates the JAR files that have been built and deployed into a cordapp folder for a node

[image]

### Questions

1. Why does `deployNodes` produce `MyFirstCorDapp-0.1.jar`? This file
   doesn't seem necessary.
2. Why is `cordapp-contracts-states-0.1.jar` so big? Given that this
   was compiled directly from the kotlin template with no changes, I'd
   expect this to be much smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why MyFirstCordapp-0.1.jar is appearing is because of this line:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
```

The root project has a kotlin plugin so creates a jar so the deployNodes deploys it.

One solution would be to use a subprojects closure to skip the root project

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform) {
    subprojects.each { subproject ->
        dependsOn(
                subproject.tasks.matching { task ->
                    (task.name == 'jar')
                }
        )
    }
```

The reason why cordapp-contracts-states-0.1.jar is "so big" (775 KB) is because the corda gradle plugin packs some dependencies in it.